# Setting boundaries to world in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi I am developing a game using libgdx framework, in that i am unable to set boundaries to the world in order to limit the actors. When ever a fixture crossed the screen(world) edge it should revert back or stop there itself. I know by calculating x,y co-ordinates we can do it, if there any other way please help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got resolved.. by setting edges to shapes