# Screen display problem in Gingerbread

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have upgraded my Motorola Atrix to Gingerbread (2.3.4), so far with no issues. When I go for  my old apps and games which I developed previously, those are not displayed fully in the screen, it is only giving a 320x480-pixel display. Do I need to change my code or my phone settings?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of this?

Comment: Do you have [`<supports-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) or  [`<compatible-screens-element>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) entries in your `AndroidManifest.xml` that might need an update or complete removal?

Comment: @Philipp Reichart sry i don't have more than 10 reputations and
i didn't include that element in my manifest file

Comment: Now you do, please post a screenshot. You might also want to accept your own answer to your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730981/setting-boundaries-to-world-in-libgdx) to mark it a resolved.

Comment: What's the values of your `android:minSdkVersion`, `android:targetSdkVersion` and `android:maxSdkVersion`?

Comment: i have set only android:minSdkVersion="1"

Comment: Could you try with `minSdkVersion="4"` or settings [`anyDensity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#any) to `true` -- both should have the same effect of allowing your app to scale beyond Android 1.0 screen sizes of 240x320.

Comment: Glad to help you -- I posted an answer below, if you'd be so kind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you currently use `android:minSdkVersion="1"`, try setting `minSdkVersion="4"` or setting [`anyDensity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#any) to `true`.

Both should have the same effect of allowing your app to scale beyond Android 1.0 screen sizes of 240x320; before SDK 4 (Android 1.6 ) the default was not to scale as there was only a single resolution.

Comment: +1 I had the same exact problem and same exact hardware as the OP.  Thank you for a solution to this annoying issue.  Would have taken me a long time to even consider that.